# Unity QRCode decode results return null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zxing

I have a C#/.Net application that decodes multiple QR codes from images on disk. I want to do this inside **Unity**, so I imported zxing plugin and modified the code so that it now uses Color32[], instead of the Bitmap Class (since Unity does not support System.Drawing.Bitmap). Following is what I have inside Unity:

```
    var fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2,2);
    texture.LoadImage(fileData);

    var barcodeBitmap = texture.GetPixels32 ();
    LuminanceSource source = new Color32LuminanceSource (barcodeBitmap, texture.width, texture.height);

    IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader ();
    Result[] results = reader.DecodeMultiple (source);
    if (results != null)
    {
        foreach (Result result in results)
        {
            Debug.Log(result.Text);
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is that contrary to before, results array always returns null, even for the ones that were not null for the .Net application that I have already tested. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Try to debug your piece of code step by step and look when something goes wrong

Comment: You can find what you need [here](https://github.com/kefniark/UnityBarcodeScanner/blob/master/Assets/Samples/Simple/SimpleDemo.cs). That's a qrcode API that actually works with Unity

Comment: Figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading jpeg or png, it should work fine. 
However, `LoadImage` for bmp does not work correctly, which returns null for you.
In order to load files of type bmp correctly, you could use

`private static readonly B83.Image.BMP.BMPLoader bmpImageLoader = new B83.Image.BMP.BMPLoader ();`

Then load it by:

```
texture = bmpImageLoader.LoadBMP(filePath).ToTexture2D();
```

Comment: I figured this problem out before as I said above, but nonetheless this is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use ZXing.NET NuGet

```
using ZXing;
using ZXing.Client.Result;
using ZXing.Common;
using ZXing.QrCode;

var QRreader= new ZXing.QrCode.QRCodeReader();
var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(filePath);
var result = QRreader.decode(barcodeBitmap);
if (result != null)
{
   Debug.Log(result.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But I am actually trying to migrate the .Net project to Unity to avoid the assumption that users have .Net download on their PC. I am going through the debugger as suggested above and I realize Color32LuminanceSource() returns height and width of 8, whereas my original image size is 640x480, so I will look into how to fix that.